# Wrong url parsing

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework

I have usual url, where params and values are separated by /

And i have this url piece

```
word//show-count/1
```

On my local machine zend retrieves

```
word = ''
show-count = '1'
```

On test-machine it retrieves

```
word = 'show\-count'
```

Why it happens and who is guilty. I think, that problem is in ignoring double //

Comment: why would you even presume that word//show-count/1 is "usual"?

Comment: What does your route look like? Is it a wildcard route? Are you using the same version of ZF on both machines? Is the PHP configuration (php.ini) the same (regarding flags) on both machines?

Comment: Are the configs different on the machines (magic quotes? safe mode?)?

Comment: Proble was in apache configuration.
But i had solved it by wiping empty parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Bizarre indeed. I think you need to fix the fact that there is a // in there in the first place.

Comment: I think it just means that "word" parameter is empty.

Comment: that's right and it should be fine, but his example is giivng him probs so a solution would be to fix the blank //